# Facebook Graph API: FB.login() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the new Facebook Graph API on my website. This is what I have:

Somewhere on the page:

```html
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Right after the  tag:

```html
<div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBAppId"] %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

            /* All the events registered */
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
                // do something with response
                alert("login success");
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
                // do something with response
                alert("logout success");
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    alert("login success");
                }
            });
        };
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        } ());
    </script>
```

but when I click on the generated login button, nothing happens.

In addition, I'm getting

```html
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

in Firebug console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I can't believe it, I was referencing a non existing key in the Web.config hence FB.init was failing silently.

It works as expected now.

**To be clearer** I wasn't passing the appId to FB.init, once I did, it worked.

Comment: which means, I wasn't passing a key to the FB.init method.

Comment: i am having same issue but only on FF on MAC osx, it works in all other browser. please help me on this. check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338198/facebook-login-plugin-issue-with-ff-on-mac-osx

Comment: Can you please post the whole working code. I'm having the same issue here. Thanks

Comment: In my case, I had missing appId in FB.init. I think it was the case also in here

Comment: Nice to know I was bit by a bug in the Facebook API that's been known for two years...

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, here is the solution that worked for me. Just put the following in your head section or in other words, add the **app_id** to the source of the facebook js.

`<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem went away after I disabled the XFBML functionality (i.e. setting the `xfbml` key to `false`, removing the `fb:` namespace and the `#xfbml=1` fragment in `<script src="…">`). Good that I didn’t need it anyway.

YMMV, there are several other valid reasons why this error message can appear.