# FaceBook Login Button Error: FB.login() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am getting this error after doing this code:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'realIdInTheCode',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
   });
 </script>

<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=realIdInTheCode&amp;xfbml=1">
</script><fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Which to my thinking is calling the init() before the login()

But I still get that error: Error: FB.login() called before calling FB.init().

I am in kind of total confusion at this point, so I'd really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Why do you have two "fb-root" div elements and two script elements for facebook javascript?

Comment: Most likely because I am a bit lost in what I am doing and the right way to go about things here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it turned out to be some problem with the app itself.  So I deleted the old app in FB and made a new one, and things just started to work.

Answer (score 4):

I used to think FBML was deprecated. I've just tested, this works for me

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
          //initializing API
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'MYAPPID', status: true, cookie: true,
                     xfbml: true});
          };
          (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
              '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
        </script>

        <button type="button" onclick="fblogin();">Facebook Login</button>


        <script>
          //your fb login function
          function fblogin() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                //User logged in!
                if (response.session) {
                    alert('YAY!');
                } else {
                // user cancelled login
                    alert('NAY!');
                }

            }, {perms:'email,read_stream,publish_stream'});
          }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**OR**

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
            <script>
              FB.init({
                appId  : 'MYAPPID',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
              });

            </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="fblogin();">Facebook Login</button>
        <script>
          //your fb login function
          function fblogin() {
              FB.login(function(response) {
                  //User logged in!
                  if (response.session) {
                      alert('YAY!');
                  } else {
                  // user cancelled login
                      alert('NAY!');
                  }

              }, {perms:'email,read_stream,publish_stream'});
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

refer:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.login/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: I made a test page for it: http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php  -- give it a try...doesn't work :(

Comment: @Genadinik Possibly stumbled-upon wrong APPID see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855784/facebook-graph-api-fb-login-called-before-calling-fb-init

Comment: @Genadinik hmm probably Not. Can you try removing all the JS related to Facebook and `<FB:..` tags. Don't just comment. remove them. Except the one in the script. I have just tested all the three approached mentioned as answers.. they all work!

Comment: I triple-checked that I am using the right app id.  But still nothing. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'realIdInTheCode',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.  I have a suspicion it has something to do with other things on the ComeHike.com site.  Not sure if anyone can spot something unusual there?