# Where to place the code of the function FB.login

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

I am wondering where should I place the FB.login functione in my web app as there is an error "FB is undefined" when running in IE 8.

However, after I refresh it, the error disappeared.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet or the structure of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

[FaceBook Login Button Error: FB.login() called before calling FB.init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909638/facebook-login-button-error-fb-login-called-before-calling-fb-init)

you should load fb library asynchronously. (independant)
Once it's loaded => window.fbAsyncInit can be run and you won't get the occasional loading behaviour anymore.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'MYAPPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});        
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

// Once all is loaded
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            //User logged in!
            if (response.session) {
                alert('YAY!');
            }
        }, {perms:'email,read_stream,publish_stream'});
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: But placing there will trigger the function when loading the page. I wanna trigger the function by clicking on a button.

Comment: "FB.login opens a popup window, and therefore you should only call FB.login when bound to a user driven click. Most browsers block popups, unless they were initiated from a user event, such as a click on a button or a link."

    ===> So, where should i place the code if i want the function initiated from a user click?